# C++: What is the difference between int *x[5] and int (*x)[5]?

Tags: c++, pointers

Do they both mean the same thing? Does their meaning differ between C and C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can answer this kind of question for yourself using http://cdecl.org/ (paste in the type and it tells you what it means in English).

> Do they both mean the same thing?

No.

> Does their meaning differ between C and C++?

No.

`int* a[5]` is an array of five pointers to int.

`int (*a)[5]` is a pointer to an array of five ints.

Comment: I am eternally grateful for tracks website. I now understand the difference.

Comment: However, it is still possible to use int * a to point to the array just like int * a[5], and both are interchangeable. Is pointer arithmetic check performed on int * a[5] if the pointer is moved to non-existent 6th element?

Comment: @quantum231, C and C++ don't require any pointer arithmetic checking. And they're not interchangeable. `int* a1[5]; int (*a2)[5]; *a1 = *a2;` compiles ok, but `*a2 = *a1;` doesn't. Figuring out why is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 5):

Use the right-left rule.

Start at the variable declaration -- `x`.

Now read right until you run into a top-level `,`, a `;` or an unbalanced closing `)` or the end of the declaration.

Read left until you find the matching `(`.  Repeat from the start.

```
x) // x
(*x) // is a pointer to
(*x)[5]; // an array of 5 elements
int (*x)[5]; // of integers

x[5]; // x is an array of 5 elements
*x[5]; // of pointers to
int *x[5]; // integers
```

Simple!

Answer (score 3):

**They are not same:**

`int * a[5]` is an array of five elements, each element is an int pointer.

`int (*a)[5]` is a pointer to an array, this array contain five int elements.

This meaning is same in c and c++.

For fast, using http://cdecl.org/ (not recommended)

For understanding, read [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations) (recommended)

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, the 2 declarations meaning does not change.
In C and C++ declarations, '[]' has higher priority than '*' when combining with variables. So, in int * x[5] declaration, x is combined with [5], so it is an 5 element array of int*. In int (*x)[5] declaration, however, x is forced to combine with '*' by use of '()', so now x is a pointer to int[5].